# Is it possible to get column names from an relation even if result rows are zero?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In Rails, one uses ActiveRecord for querying the database.  ActiveRecord's query results in an ActiveRecord::Relation object.  Since we can execute `ActiveRecord::Relation#select` and specify arbitrary SQL select clause, sometimes the records returned by the database contains columns which does not exist in the database.

If this relation contains more than one row, then one can get the column names of the relation by using `the_relation.first.attributes`.  When no records were returned by the query, however, this method is not possible.

#### Question

- Is there any way to get the Query's resulting column names of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` even if no rows were returned?

#### The motivation

For example, when you're building an `Daru::DataFrame` instance or some other Relational Data, you'd want to obtain the attribute names even if there is no records in the result.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can get the column names

If the result is ActiveRecord::Relation then you can use something like this

```
the_relation.column_names
```

Comment: Actually, `the_relation.column_names` will return the column names of target table.  Not the column names created by the select statement.  For example, `SomeModel.select('1 as one').column_names` would return columns of `some_models`, not `['one']`

Comment: if you use select on any model then the results class will be an array it will not be an ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: Refer to the second functionality of `ActiveRecord.select` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select